# Parsing an order file, grouping by stock symbol and calculating the average order price with quantity

Tags: scala

I have a flat file that contains a list of stock purchases for a given day.

```
Symbol  Quantity  Price  ACTION     Datetime

ABC     100       5.25   BUY        20210609 09:20:10
ABC     100       5.35   SELL       20210609 09:20:10
ABC     100       5.25   BUY        20210609 09:20:10
ABC     100       5.20   BUY        20210609 09:20:10
DEF     500       1.25   BUY        20210609 09:20:10
ABC     200       5.50   SELL       20210609 09:20:10
DEF     250       1.50   SELL        20210609 09:20:10
DEF     250       1.00   SELL        20210609 09:20:10
```

Summary

```
Order#1   ABC  100  ...
Order#2   ABC  200  ...
Order#3   DEF 500 ...
```

I have each row represented as a case class, and I have a the data already loaded in a Map:
1. Key is the stock symbol
2. The collection is all transactions for that stock symbol

```
case class Order(symbol: String, time: Instant, quantity: Int, price: BigDecimal)

case class CompletedOrder(symbol: String, quantity: Int, avgPrice: BigDecimal)

val transactions: Map[String, Seq[Transaction]] = ???
```

I want to loop through all the orders for a given stock, and group them together such that each buy/sell will be considered a completed transaction.

For each symbol the transactions will be ordered by the datetime. so basically the logic is as follows:

```
1. If there is a Buy order, keep adding the quantity to the symbol in an existing CompletedOrder, create if necessary
2. If there is a Sell order, subtract the quantity until you reach 0.  
    If you reach 0, consider the order to be completed.
```

Now I can do the above in a forloop, but I was curious how I can do this in a more **functional style** like using a
`.fold()` and returning a `Seq[CompleteOrder]`.

Comment: the key is the `symbol`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez so is this map mutable then?

Comment: So, `CompletedOrder` is actually completed, when the quantity is zero? And if it is not 0, then it is incomplete competed order? What is involved in "considering the order to be completed"? Do you want the output to only have completed  Complete Orders? And Incomplete Complete ones should be discarded?  What is average price? Is it average buy price? Average sell price? Both? How does a sell order affect average price? How do you tell a buy Order from a sell Order? What is a `Transaction`?

Comment: > `Now I can do the above in a forloop`
-- Perhaps, you should ... because the way you described what you are trying to do so far makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:
Using a `foldLeft` where your accumulator is a tuple of a `Seq[CompleteOrder]` and a `Map[symbol, (quantity, avgPrice)]` and then for each element you either remove something from the **Map** and append a new **CompleteOrder** to the **Seq**, or add a new entry to the **Map**.

```scala
import java.time.Instant

sealed trait Action extends Product with Serializable
object Action {
  final case object Buy extends Action
  final case object Sell extends Action
}

final case class Transaction(symbol: String, time: Instant, quantity: Int, price: BigDecimal, action: Action)
final case class CompletedOrder(symbol: String, quantity: Int, avgPrice: BigDecimal)

def reduceTransactions(data: List[Transaction]): List[CompletedOrder] = {
  val (completedOrders, remainingTransactions) =
    data.sortBy(_.time).foldLeft(List.empty[CompletedOrder] -> Map.empty[String, (Int, BigDecimal)]) {
      case ((completedOrdersAcc, transactionsMap), Transaction(symbol, _, quantity, price, action)) =>
        action match {
          case Action.Buy =>
            completedOrdersAcc -> transactionsMap.updatedWith(key = symbol) {
              case None =>
                Some(quantity -> price)
              
              case Some((prevQuantity, prevAvgPrice)) =>
                val newQuantity = prevQuantity + quantity
                val newAvgPrice = ((prevAvgPrice * prevQuantity) + (quantity + price)) / newQuantity
                Some(newQuantity, newAvgPrice)
            }
          
          case Action.Sell =>
            transactionsMap.get(key = symbol) match {
              case Some((totalQuantity, avgPrice)) if (totalQuantity == quantity) =>
                (CompletedOrder(symbol, quantity, avgPrice) :: completedOrdersAcc) ->
                  transactionsMap.removed(key = symbol)
                
              case Some((totalQuantity, avgPrice)) if (totalQuantity > quantity) =>
                (CompletedOrder(symbol, quantity, avgPrice) :: completedOrdersAcc) ->
                  transactionsMap.updated(key = symbol, value = ((totalQuantity - quantity), avgPrice))
              
              case _ =>
                // Invalid transaction, panic!
                throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal transaction!")
            }
        }
    }
  
  if (remainingTransactions.nonEmpty) {
    // Is this an error? Or should those also be returned?
    println("Remaining transactions:")
    remainingTransactions.valuesIterator.foreach(println)
  }
  
  completedOrders.reverse
}
```

You may want to adjust many aspects of this function like how to treat errors and adjust the computations of averages. You may even prefer to use a tail-recursive function rather than the `foldLeft`; probably you should also split the big body into multiple reusable and testable functions for each case.

Anyways, feel free to ask any questions you may have.